# HTML onclick открыть картинку

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Хочу при нажатие на кнопку, что бы открывал картинку и закрывал ее. Нашел такой код, на одном сайте. Сижу пробую через нее открыть картинку, не выходит. Код выглядит вполне приличным, вот и пробую. Может кто подскажет, как это можно было бы сделать ?

Еще вопрос, картинку лучше через URL ставить, или указывать путь из папки ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    #myDIV {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 50px 0;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: lightblue;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
  </div>

  <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Замените содержимое дива на картинку вместо текста. Сейчас вы просто меняете состояние свойства `display`, которое отвечает за отображение блока: показать или нет.

Comment: Что Вас не устраивает в текущем поведении (см. работающий пример в вопросе), и при чем здесь "картинка"?